# dotnet command doesn't find new install of .NET Core 2.1

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am attempting to host ASP.NET Core applications on my Debian 9 server. I had previously installed .NET Core 1, and have been trying to install the runtime/hosting for .NET 2.1.

I've followed the [official installation instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux-package-manager/debian9/runtime-current) for my distribution, however the `dotnet --version` command outputs 1.0.1, and `dotnet --info` outputs

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.1)

Product Information:
 Version:            1.0.1
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  005db40cd1

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     debian
 OS Version:  9
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         debian.8-x64
 Base Path:   /opt/dotnet/sdk/1.0.1
```

when I try to run just the basic template application that I've copied to the server, it outputs

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      /opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.1.1
      1.0.4
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '2.1.0'.
```

Sure enough, `/opt/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App` only contains subdirectories for 1.1.1 and 1.0.4, yet...

```
$ sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-2.1
   [sudo] password for root:
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   aspnetcore-runtime-2.1 is already the newest version (2.1.2-1).
```

What do I have to do to get the runtime to be found?

**Answers to questions in comments:**

```
$ which dotnet
/usr/local/bin/dotnet
```

The output of dpkg -L is quite long, but I think gives me the reason for my problem. The files for the 2.1 runtime are all under `/usr/share/dotnet` instead of `/opt/dotnet`. Running `dotnet` uses the one in `/usr/local/bin` that sees the old runtime, but it looks like there's a `/usr/bin/dotnet` that looks at the new version... I followed Microsoft's instructions for both installs, so I'm not sure why it's so different.

Comment: How are you creating the template application artifacts that you are copying to the debian server? For instance, are you using `dotnet build` or `dotnet publish`?

Comment: Can you run `which dotnet` and `dpkg -L aspnetcore-runtime-2.1`?

Comment: @omajid I've added information regarding that to the end of the question, which led to me solving the issue. If you make an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin It was created in Windows with Visual Studio, using the built-in "Publish" dialog, folder deploy framework-dependent.

Comment: One more request: can you `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @omajid `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games` -- I reckon swapping the first two would do the trick in my case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you enter `dotnet` on your command line, your shell looks for it in your `$PATH`. You seem to have two `dotnet` commands installed, one at `/usr/local/bin/dotnet`, and another one at `/usr/bin/dotnet`. `/usr/local/bin/` appears first in your `$PATH` so your shell runs `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` when you type `dotnet`.

`/usr/local/bin/dotnet` is, I suspect, a symlink to `/opt/dotnet/dotnet`. That one contains 2 .NET Core runtime versions (as indicated by `dotnet --info`): 1.0.4 and 1.1.1. It sounds like this was installed manually by a user, possibly by extracting from a release tarball to `/opt/dotnet`.

(These version are very out of date. They also contain known security vulnerabilities)

`/usr/share/dotnet/` is installed by the `dotnet-*` and `aspnetcore*` packages via `apt`. And that contains verison 2.1 packages.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

1. If `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` is not owned by the package manager (`dpkg --search /usr/local/bin/dotnet` doesn't list a package), then you can simply `rm` it. Then `dotnet` will mean `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet`. You can also remove `/opt/dotnet`.
2. If `/usr/local/bin/dotnet` is owned by a package manager, find the name of the package in the `dpkg --search` output and remove that package.
3. You can override `$PATH` in your `.bashrc` (or equivalent shell profile). Add a line like `export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/game`.

I strongly recommend option 1.

I am not sure why the two were installed in different locations and with different executibles. Perhaps the installation instructions were changed and packages were made available after the release of the versions you installed?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I had installed very early on in the release, and believe I may have cloned/downloaded the tarball from github. Don't recall for sure but do remember it being much more work than the instructions on microsoft's site.